# Is $\left\{\sum_{k=1}^n a_k^{1/2}\right\}^2$ homogeneous of order one?

Tags: calculus

I think it is homogeneous of order one, but the book says it is homogeneous of order two. I just want a confirmation.

Let $F(a_1,a_2,...,a_n) = \left\{\sum_{k=1}^n a_k^{1/2}\right\}^2$, then

$$F(wa_1,wa_2,...,wa_n) = \left\{\sum_{k=1}^n (wa_k)^{1/2}\right\}^2 = \left\{w^{1/2}\sum_{k=1}^n (a_k)^{1/2}\right\}^2 = w \left\{\sum_{k=1}^n (a_k)^{1/2}\right\}^2?$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right.

> Since  a function $F(a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n)$ is *[homogeneous of order one](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EulersHomogeneousFunctionTheorem.html)* iff 
>   \begin{align*}
> F(wa_1,wa_2,\ldots,w_an)=wF(a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n)
> \end{align*}
>   and
>   \begin{align*}
> F(wa_1,wa_2,\ldots,wa_n) &= \left\{\sum_{k=1}^n (wa_k)^{1/2}\right\}^2\\
> &=w\left\{\sum_{k=1}^n a_k^{1/2}\right\}^2\\
> &=wF(a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n)
> \end{align*}
>   we  conclude that $F$ is homogeneous of order one.